# jQuery is not defined error

Tags: jquery

Error in Jquery

In view file (index.php)

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="crosscut.js" ></script> 
 <script src="jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="mod-min.js" ></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-min.js" ></script>
```

In Javascript file

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#crossline').css('background-color','blue');
});

button = function() {
   // other code
}
```

I have included jquery-min.js in script and it is loaded on page loading. jquery-min.js all code loaded while inspecting through firebug .

If file may be corrupted ,So I tried live path of "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" still not works.

If calling javascript function uses jquery works fine if ready function not set .

Comment: Are there any other jQuery files loaded??? There might be a conflict

Comment: are you sure you are including the jquery lib *before the above code ?

Comment: jQuery UI is also included;   var jq = $.noConflict();
jq(document).ready(function() {
    jq('#crossline').css('background-color','blue');
});
$ is not defined error

Comment: Just paste your code into the question. You haven't provided anything that could help anyone determine what's wrong.

Comment: @jim : I have included all lib in view file in script tags

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're not providing much info, but one issue you have is that you're loading `jQueryUI` *before* you load `jQuery`.

Any other files that rely on jQuery must be loaded *after* jQuery as well.

```
    <!-- this one first! -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-min.js" ></script>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="crosscut.js" ></script> 
 <script src="jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="mod-min.js" ></script>
```

Comment: Good things seem to always come from you +1 :)

Answer (score -1):

if you are using jQuery.js load jQuery.js first and then other js
Sequence also important.

```
    <script src="js/jQuery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>      
    <script src="js/jQuery.alert.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/CustomerSummary.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css"></link>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style_new.css" type="text/css"></link>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @swati. I understand what you have trying to say, but it is already given in other answer and accepted. It is not appreciable to duplicate answer. One question, Why you are including two jQuery versions `js/jQuery.js` and `js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js` in sample code? It is not recommended to have two jQuery versions in one page.

Comment: @justin i required JQuery.js for different functionality and it work fine for me. thanks for your comment.