# Webpack x Symfony 5 - JQuery is not defined

Tags: jquery, symfony, webpack

Tonight I decided to start learning to use Webpack and Encore.

Just started and I already got a problem: Jquery does not exist in my templates but it does in my console.

**How did i get here:**

- First I downloaded the depencies: `composer require symfony/webpack-encore-bundle; yarn install; yarn add jquery --dev`
- Then, I built my assets: `yarn encore dev --watch`
- I updated my assets/app.js file so it (*should?)* imports Jquery: `... import $ from 'jquery'; ...`
- Finally, I wrote my code in my templates/base.html.twig file:

```
        {{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}
        <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function(){
                console.log('ok');
            })
        </script>
       {% block javascripts %}{% endblock %}
```

I did all this following [Symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/simple-example.html#requiring-javascript-modules).

**What I tried:**

- I tried playing with the `import $ from 'jquery'` line, using `const`, `require`, and so on...
- I tried using `<script src="{{asset('build/app.js')}}"></script>`instead of `{{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}`.
- I tried to build my assets as prod env instead of dev.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194992/jquery-is-not-defined https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8373357/jquery-is-not-defined-error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8886614/uncaught-referenceerror-jquery-is-not-defined

Comment: Nope, this is not working.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed it by adding `const $ = require('jquery'); global.$ = global.jQuery = $;` in the assets/app.js file.

Comment: Please do not answer by editing/updating the question - post a complete answer in the answer space, as I have edited yours.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using Webpack Encore you don't need to manually define jQuery via a Js file. You can simply include it in your WebpackConfig by adding the following to your `webpack.config.js` file:

```js
Encore
  // your Encore config (outputPath, publicPath, ...)
  .autoProvidejQuery()
```

Which is equivalent to:

```js
WebpackConfig.autoProvideVariables({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery'
});
```

Or when using Webpack without Encore:

```js
var webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery'
    })
  ],
}
```

*When making changes to your `webpack.config.js` file, make sure to stop and restart Webpack / Encore.*